# React Native: ViewManager for tag could not be found

Tags: android, react-native

We are getting several of the following errors when running `logcat` in our React Native Android app. Intially they seem harmless and they doesn't crash the app. However, if possible I'd like to get some guidance on how to debug them to understand what's going on.

```
Unable to update properties for view tag 323
com.facebook.react.uimanager.IllegalViewOperationException: ViewManager for tag 323 could not be found.
 View already dropped? false.
Last index 0 in last 100 views[I@1eeace9
   at com.facebook.react.uimanager.NativeViewHierarchyManager.resolveViewManager(NativeViewHierarchyManager.java:112)
   at com.facebook.react.uimanager.NativeViewHierarchyManager.updateProperties(NativeViewHierarchyManager.java:135)
   at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIImplementation.synchronouslyUpdateViewOnUIThread(UIImplementation.java:309)
   at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerModule.synchronouslyUpdateViewOnUIThread(UIManagerModule.java:396)
   at com.facebook.react.animated.PropsAnimatedNode.updateView(PropsAnimatedNode.java:94)
   at com.facebook.react.animated.NativeAnimatedNodesManager.updateNodes(NativeAnimatedNodesManager.java:544)
   at com.facebook.react.animated.NativeAnimatedNodesManager.runUpdates(NativeAnimatedNodesManager.java:453)
   at com.facebook.react.animated.NativeAnimatedModule$1.doFrameGuarded(NativeAnimatedModule.java:100)
   at com.facebook.react.uimanager.GuardedFrameCallback.doFrame(GuardedFrameCallback.java:29)
   at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ReactChoreographer$ReactChoreographerDispatcher.doFrame(ReactChoreographer.java:172)
   at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ChoreographerCompat$FrameCallback$1.doFrame(ChoreographerCompat.java:84)
   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:965)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:791)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:722)
   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:952)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

**EDIT:** Just for reference we are using `react-native` 0.60.5, `react-navigation` 3.13.0 and `react-native-paper` 3.10.1. Also, we see these errors when we first open the app.

Thanks!

Comment: Solve it? I encountered the same problem

Comment: Not yet. I will add more info about the packages we are using, which might help.

Comment: After I reinstalled `node_modules`, this problem disappeared.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I was using the properties `flex` and `padder` of a `View` from Native Base after the property `style`. When I moved the two properties before the `style` property everything starts working ‍♂️

Answer (score 3):

Faced this problem recently, we had a common package that had UI Components for both web and mobile. A component was using the css property 'inherit'. This is fine in web, but it caused the crash in mobile.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was a mistake it was a typo in a style.

Answer (score 0):

I made a silly mistake by adding `overflow: true` to my styles (even though I have no idea why I added it :-P). The code crashed with the above error, but when I replaced it with `overflow: 'hidden'`, it worked fine.